# Eclipse change 'view' border color

Tags: eclipse, colors, grid, border

Is there a way to change the color of the grids in eclipse?

I am using the built-in 'Dark' theme, and the grid lines are too bright for me, they mess with my vision, I have some visual snow.

[image]

Comment: @greg-449 updated my answer, it is indeed customizable.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is based on the "Window Color and Appearance" (that's the given name if you are under windows) of your desktop personalization just like the top bar maximize/minimize/close.

So you can always go there and change it in "3D objects", but be aware that this change will affect your whole desktop/windows visuals.

Altho, that beeing said, I know that there are ways tweak it around. This could give you a hand: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-4-chrome-theme#.UYrzEkAW1J0

Also a tool called css spy will help you find what you want to edit faster: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-4-tools-css-spy#.UYrzSkAW1J0

Comment: I installed both
In Jeeeyul's I can't find where I could change this.
CSS Spy doesn't seem to work when I press shift+alt+f5, it just defocuses the window.
I have Eclipse 4.4.0.

Comment: I managed to change the color through Color and Appearance, but I don't want my system to look like that.
Since eclipse uses a windows api for this I guess it should be near impossible to change it, the plugin would have to have an own system for ui.